# return User Quota with PHP from Linux OS

Tags: php, linux, quota

I need to find out quota details for the current user,

I`ve tried 
exec("quota 'username'", $retParam) 
and also system() but nothing is returned.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user PHP runs under is probably not allowed to get other users' quotas - maybe not even its own, or maybe it's not even allowed to execute external commands. Depending on your server setup, you may be able to change PHP's configuration (remove safe_mode for example) and elevate the rights of the PHP user, but I don't know whether that's a wise thing to do. If you are on shared hosting, you would have to speak to your provider whether anything can be done.

[**This blog entry**](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20041205173932493) outlines a clever way to get around PHP's limitations by collecting all quotas in a text file in an external cron job, and parsing that file with PHP. Works only if you have access to the server, of course, or can set up cron jobs with more liberal permissions than the PHP user.

Comment: I just want to return quota for the current user;

I have root access also.

Comment: @claudiu In that case, the method suggested in the blog entry may be the best one.

Comment: I`ve tried that but it gave me an error:
Warning: file(/tmp/quotas) [function.file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I`ve browsed tmp folder and there is no quotas file/folder :(

Comment: @claudiu you probably need to create the file elsewhere, in a directory the PHP user has access to.

Comment: that script is working, let`s if I`ll manage to display specifically what I need

Comment: It appears the relevant blog entry can now be found at: https://www.afp548.com/2004/12/06/disk-quota-reporting-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

To give a code example and extend the above answer

You need root access + a directory that is readable by your webserver.

do `crontab -e`

and add

```
0 * * * * quota -u -s someusername | grep /dev > /path/to/webserver/quota.txt
```

The above line will save the quota of user `someusername` in quota.txt located in the webserver folder every hour.

Then write a PHP file to show it

```
$quota_txt= file_get_contents("quota.txt");
$quota_arr = explode("   ",$quota_txt);
function rm_g($str){
return intval(substr_replace($str, "", -1));

}
echo "total quota: ". $quota_arr[4]."<br>";
echo "used: ". $quota_arr[3]."<br>";
$free =(rm_g($quota_arr[4]))-rm_g($quota_arr[3]);
echo "free: " . $free . "G";
```

Not perfect, and it need to be adapted if you are in a use-case where the human-readable format is not G (gigabytes), in that case remove the `-s` and parse bytes then convert the bytes output to human-readable in PHP

Also as you may have guessed, the cronjob is hourly, which means user is not getting realtime stats, there might be some inconsistencies. you may want to increase the frequency of the cron.

Another intensive approach is to get quota as above, but do `du` every time to get really used space. (look for "get folder size with PHP efficiently" here and you will find codes). This will get you the real-time remaining quota